# placement of node in pgfplots axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How do I specify the position of a node in a coordinate system? I tried the following, but instead of the triangle being centered at (1.1,0.2) it is placed next to it. What am I missing please?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
\addplot+ coordinates{(1, 0.2)};
\node[color=red] at (axis cs:1.1, 0.2) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpicture]

Actually, eventually I would like to *tip* of the triangle to be placed at (1.1,0.2). Is that easy to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easyily add `\(...\)`. You can replace `{\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}}` with `{\(\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}\)}`.

result:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
\addplot+ coordinates{(1, 0.2)};
% \node[color=red] at (axis cs:1.1, 0.2) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}}; old
\node[color=green,scale=1]  at (axis cs:1.1, 0.2) {\(\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}\)} ; %<-new line
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: _This_ approach centers my triangle! I am still using `pgfplots 1.11'. @Bobyandbob why does this work?

Comment: Because I put `\pgfuseplotmark` in the text box.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code using `pgfplots 2016/08/10 v1.14`, the triangle *is* centered. Check whether you use the latest version.

To position the triangle with its tip, you can define your own plotmark `mytriangle` (a modification of `triangle*`):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pgf@plot@mark@mytriangle
  {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{-60}{2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{-120}{2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
   \pgfpathclose\pgfusepathqfillstroke
  }
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\pgf@plot@mark@mytriangle
  {\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{-60}{2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpointpolar{-120}{2\pgfplotmarksize}}%
   \pgfpathclose\pgfusepathqfillstroke
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
\addplot+ coordinates{(1, 0.2)};
\node[color=red] at (axis cs:1.1, 0.2) {\pgfuseplotmark{mytriangle}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: with `pgfplots 1.11` the `axis cs:` is default coordinate system.

Comment: @gernot it turns out that am using `pgfplots.sty 2014/08/04 v1.11`. I will install a more recent version of it to see whether the triangle gets centered. @Zarko in case you use `pgfplots 1.11`, is your triangle centered?

Comment: hm, I tested with 1.11 and its works as I reported. Note, node is actually `rectangle` and its content is `\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}` (to see this, add to node option `\draw` ).  This means, that node wold be always centered, but contents more or less accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have particular reason that you don't mark as such?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
\addplot[mark=triangle*,red]  coordinates{(1, 0.2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

if you persist with use of node, than your example with `pgfplots 1.14` work as expected. Triangle is centered on given coordinate:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
\addplot+ coordinates{(1, 0.2)};
\node[color=red] at (1.1, 0.2) {\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Addendum:*
Node is perfectly centered (to see this, add option `draw` to the node), but node content is not necessary centered in node. This seems to be your problem, which is not related to `pgfplots`.

So, if you like to use node, than see if the following example, in which the node has triangle shape, is acceptable solution:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major]
\addplot coordinates{(1, 0.2)};
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,
      fill=red, 
      semitransparent,
      inner sep=3pt] at (1.1, 0.2) {};% fore real use 'inner sep=1.2pt' would be more appropriate
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In a case, that you have more such nodes, you can define style for it, for example as:

```
\tikzset{mytrianglemark/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3,
                                fill=red,inner sep=1.2pt}
```

and store in preamble or after `\begin{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Still using `pgfplots 1.11`, I find your first suggestion to be perfect. The second, however, does not work for me, with the triangle being centered somewhere around coordinate (1.02, 0.201).

Comment: hm, there should be my comment about this ... seems that I append it to wrong question :(. Anyway, let me repeated: node is perfectly centered (to see this, add option`draw` to node), but node content is not necessary centered in node. This is your problem, which seems is not related to `pgfplots`.